# Как правильно указать место для расположения js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

у меня в скрипте есть строка

```js
document.body.append(div); // вставляем обёртку, куда вам нужно
```

но мне нужно вставить это в блок с классом .woosb-products

такая строка не работает

```js
.woosb-products.append(div);
```

Как правильно написать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `.append` есть у элемента. Соответственно нужно этот элемент сначала получить. `document.body` доступен всегда глобально, поэтому его получать не нужно. А в вашем случае нужно сделать так:

```
document.querySelector('.woosb-products').append(div);
```

, где `document.querySelector('.woosb-products')` возвращает элемент.